# Calling a method on NPAPI plugin object respawns the plugin

Tags: javascript, c++, npapi, browser-plugin

I have a NPAPI plugin embedded in a HTML page. When I call a method on it from browser's developer console, everything is ok - methods call lands on the right plugin instance and is properly executed. Anyway, when I call the same method from JS callback, like a button click, for instance, plugin is destroyed and the recreated again, while `NPP.pdata` is set to null.

Can it be somehow related to JS multithreading model and how can it be solved?

Comment: Something must be triggering the respawn. Please show how you are using it from JS, otherwise it's just guesswork. Also, multithreading is not really involved here - plugin calls and most JS happen on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for your considerations - the problem, in fact had nothing to do with NPAPI - I was using a button, and on click it was reloading the page (I didn't noticed it).

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe add an answer here for future reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue was not related to NPAPI, or JS multithreading at all.

I was calling a method on NPAPI plugin object in a HTML form.

```
<form>
    <input id="whatever-button" type="submit" value="Whatever"></input>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#whatever-button').click(function(e) {
        var plugin = document.getElementById('plugin');
        plugin.whatever();
    });
</script>
```

What I have not considered is the page reload - which is the default action after a click on a button. Page reload then triggered plugin object recreation, and it was fast enough, so I have not noticed it. The problem is solved by simply adding `e.preventDefault();` to the callback function. This is how the working code looks like.

```
<embed id="plugin" type="application/my-npapi-plugin" width="640" height="480">

<form>
    <input id="whatever-button" type="submit" value="Whatever"></input>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#whatever-button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var plugin = document.getElementById('plugin');
        plugin.whatever();
    });
</script>
```

UPD: Actually, setting input type to `button`, instead of `submit` is easier way to solve the issue. It also does not require `e.preventDefault();`.